# Python memory related and time consumption related

Tags: python-3.x

I have a huge file of around 80mb from which I am generating one other file which orders the data. But as the file size is very huge , the program wrote by me is taking a lot of time (around 1Hr).So how to reduce the time duration?

Below is the content of the file.

Logging at 1/20/2019 12:00:00 AM
Test Manager | 1706
TestStandEngineWrapper | 1403
Logging at 1/20/2019 12:00:01 AM
Test Manager | 1706
TestStandEngineWrapper | 1403

Like this there are thousands of entries which I am trying to order in the below format.

I am arranging them in the below format.

Test Manager | 1706 | Logging at 1/20/2019 12:00:00 AM
Test Manager | 1706 | Logging at 1/20/2019 12:00:01 AM
TestStandEngineWrapper | 1403 | Logging at 1/20/2019 12:00:00 AM
TestStandEngineWrapper | 1403 | Logging at 1/20/2019 12:00:01 AM

```
import re
file=open("C:\\Users\\puru\\Desktop\\xyz.txt","rt")
file1=open("C:\\Users\\puru\\Desktop\\xyz1.txt","wt")
file1.write("")
arr1=file.readlines()
str1=""
str2=""
arr2=[]
arr3=[]
arr4=[]
#for j in iter(file.readline, ''):

for i,j in enumerate (arr1):
    if "Logging" in j:
        str1=j
    elif "Logging" not in j:
        arr3.append(j.split("|")[0])
        str2=j.rstrip()+" | "+str1
        arr2.append(str2)
        str2=""

for i in arr3:
    if i not in arr4:
        arr4.append(i)

for j in arr4:
    for k in arr2:
        if re.match(j,k):
            file1=open("C:\\Users\\puru\\Desktop\\xyz1.txt","at")
            file1.write(k)

file1.close()
file.close()
```

Though I am getting the desired output ,as it takes a lot of time ,it is not that useful. Could you please suggest something to reduce the time?

Comment: I think the main problem is the time taken to read. File I/O operations are very slow. I think you could try threading to read the file. Perhaps you should try to time various parts of your code to determine which part is taking the most time. And also, how much time is it taking? If it is just a one-off activity, you may not need to do it.

Comment: It would be really useful to not name variables `arr1`, `arr3`, etc because the intent of the written code is not readily clear, esp because you didn't paste the full input file (and you can't because it is too big). Plus it is not maintainable code.
I'd look into optimizing your last for loop because it is O(N^2) and for large files that will be a problem.

Comment: file1 is already open. No need to open it a 2nd time, and it is an expensive operation. If this is not enough, break the O (n^2), as already mentioned.

Comment: O (n^2)?Really don't know what is this?